# Permission error python jupyterhub. How to solve?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyterhub

I'm trying to `pandas.read_csv` from a specific folder on a UNIX platform using JUpyterHub and receiving

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('/opt/app/data/some_folder/test.csv')
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/app/data/some_folder/test.csv'
```

What is strange is that the same file is accessible if put into
`'/opt/app/data/other_folder/test.csv'`.

Both of these folder have 770 permissions and the user is member of both groups (for simplicity I use the folder name as group  name as well) related to them:

```
import os
user = os.getenv('JUPYTERHUB_USER')
gnames = [ g.gr_name for g in grp.getgrall() if user in g.gr_mem ]
gnames

['some_folder',
 'other_folder']
```

Since we have also Rstudio installed on the same server, I've tried same using R and there is no hiccup there. Same is valid for WinSCP - no issue both folders are accessible.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.